# Map the Json Array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

trying to map two Array Values. One Array Values are coming from the local Json file and other  array values are coming from the service or backend.

Local JSON:

```
var localJsonArray = {
    "records": {
        "cat1": [{
            "id": 1234,
                "label": "a"
        }, {
            "id": 2345,
                "label": "b"

        }],
            "cat2": {

            "id": 12345,
                "label": "c"
        }
    }
}
```

Backend Array Values:

I am storing the value coming from backend as:

```
var backendArray =[0: "1234", 1: "3456", 2:"4567"];
```

JS:

```
$.each( localJsonArray, function( key, value ) {
                var index = $.inArray( value, backendArray );
                if( index != -1 ) {
                    console.log( index );
                }
            });
```

Now how do I map the id of local Json to the id of backend JSON. If value matches the loop should break else it should look for the value.

Comment: where is the backend array values?

Comment: You can't create an array like that >>> 'var backendArray =[0: "1234", 1: "3456", 2:"4567"]';

Comment: But I'll create the answer... ;) ... wait a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a array like `var backendArray =[0: "1234", 1: "3456", 2:"4567"];`

So by the way ... follow the code above:

```
var localJsonArray = {
    "records": {
        "cat1": [{
            "id": 1234,
                "label": "a"
        }, {
            "id": 2345,
                "label": "b"

        }],
            "cat2": {

            "id": 12345,
                "label": "c"
        }
    }
};
var backendArray =["1234", "3456", "4567"];

$.each( localJsonArray['records'], function( a,b,c ) {
    if(!(b.length == undefined)){
        for(var i = 0;i < b.length; i++)
        {
            var index = $.inArray( b[i].id.toString(), backendArray );
            if( index != -1 ) {
                console.log( index );
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        var index = $.inArray( b.id.toString(), backendArray );
        if( index != -1 ) {
            console.log( index );
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this help!!! :)